# History command showing the directory and the date

Tags: history

Is there a way to have in the .bash_history file, listed: the directory where the command has been typed, the date, and the command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

History command showing the directory: NO! :(

History command showing the date: YES! :)

That's because (from `man history`):

> ```
> The history list is an array of history entries.  A  history  entry is
> declared as follows:
>
>    typedef void * histdata_t;
>
>    typedef struct _hist_entry {
>      char *line;
>      char *timestamp;
>      histdata_t data;
>    } HIST_ENTRY;
> ```

So, nothing about the directory where the command has been typed.

To know the exact time certain command was executed, see `help history`:

> ```
> If the $HISTTIMEFORMAT variable is set and not null, its value is used
> as a format string for strftime(3) to print the time stamp associated
> with each displayed history entry.  No time stamps are printed
> otherwise.
> ```

So all you have to do is to set `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` something like this in the current shell:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
```

To have it permanently set, run the following command:

```
echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
```

The above command will add a new line (`export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "`) at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file.

Now, the output of `history` will look something like this:

```
 ...
 1613  2013-11-13 13:00:15 cat .bash_history
 1614  2013-11-13 13:01:04 man history
 1615  2013-11-13 13:11:58 help history
 1616  2013-11-13 13:19:07 ls
 1617  2013-11-13 13:19:09 cd
 1618  2013-11-13 13:19:15 history
```

Comment: ok.. but I really really need a way to have the directory where the command has been typed. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I added this: export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T " in the .bashrc, and it doesn't work

Comment: @ApahideanIancu First reopen your terminal or `source ~/.bashrc`, then you should run `history` command to see the result.

Comment: @ApahideanIancu Also, the history commands will all be merged and written to the common `~/.bash_history` file once you exit from the terminal. The times will be saved in `~/.bash_history` in unix time format (each line where the time is saved will look something like: `#1384343470`).

Answer (score 9):

You CAN write the current working directory in a history file as well, but you have to make an own history file:

Write your .bashrc as follows:

```
export CUSTOM_HISTFILE="/tmp/bash_history" #path of the new history file
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; date | xargs echo -n >>$CUSTOM_HISTFILE; echo -n ' - ' >>$CUSTOM_HISTFILE; pwd | xargs echo -n >>$CUSTOM_HISTFILE; echo -n ' - ' >>$CUSTOM_HISTFILE; tail -n 1 $HISTFILE >>$CUSTOM_HISTFILE; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

It's a bit circumstantial, but it works. An entry could look like this:

```
Mit Nov 13 13:44:39 CET 2013 - /home/test - ls -la
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please clear your question a bit. There is a command called fc(fixed command) in ubuntu which enables you to display the history file, edit and re-execute previous command. Basically it is the alias set up for history command.

By default,

```
fc  -l lists the 16 most recent commands.
```

You can also use

```
history command itself to see the command history.
```