# How to find the directory on which a particular command is executed?

Tags: command-line, history

I already installed `nautilus-open-terminal` package. So i can openup terminal from any directory. Like that i opened a terminal from a directory(i forgot it's path) and executed `apt-get download vlc` command.

We all know, `apt-get download` command will download the package to the current directory itself. Because of I forgetted the directory path, i don't know where these packages are located.

I tried `history` command, it shows only the below commands.

```
 1986  man cdrecord
 1987  cd foo-bar
 1988  history
 1989  apt-get download vlc
```

It failed to mention the directory on which a particular command(`apt-get download vlc`) is executed. If it displays the directory, it will be easy to find the location of downloaded pacakges.

```
  1989  ~/Desktop  apt-get download vlc
```

Is that possible to make `history` command like above? Is there any way to find the directory on which a particular command is executed?

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/948515/1154487) on stackoverflow. I tried it but honestly the corrupted history commands are really painful. Unable to recall a command using !12 for exmaple.

Comment: @Radu Can you tell me which answer will work for this question?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Try them all  f you really are interested! [My answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/376417/147044) explain why you can't use `~/.bash_history` file to save the directory on which a particular command is executed and [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/376460/147044) explain how to use a custom history file for your purpose.

Comment: @Radu did you try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/376460/202806) answer? It isn't work for me.

Comment: @AvinashRaj *It's a bit circumstantial, but it works.* Just take your time to  understand it.

Comment: Please appreciate his [work](http://askubuntu.com/a/376460/202806). And i'm going to put close vote on mine.